# run a particular method using sudo

Tags: sudo

How to run a single command in rhel for a particular user

e.g: only `ls` command should execute, if we try for other commands we should get a error like `permission denied`

I am uisng visduo file and created a user and assigned a permission like

```
abhitest        ALL=(ALL)       /bin/ls
```

and I tried too `abhitest        ALL=/bin/ls`

but its not working

Comment: This would allow user `abhitest` to run `sudo -u <any other user> ls <any parameters>`, i.e. the user would be able to run the `ls` command with any parameters as any user, including root. But it would have no effect at all for commands run as user `abhitest`: if you want that, you need to set up a *restricted shell* for that user.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you refer to sudo mecanism (`visudo` is part of `sudo`)

with

```
abhitest        ALL=(ALL)       /bin/ls
```

you should be able to run, as abhitest

```
sudo /bin/ls
```

- you will be asked <s>root</s> abhitest's password. (this may or may not what you intend, assuming a real command)

try ti use in `sudoers`

```
abhitest        ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:      /bin/ls /some/secret/dir
```

you should be able, as `abhitest` to run

```
sudo /bin/ls /some/secret/dir
```

note that both

```
sudo ls /some/secret/dir
sudo /bin/ls /some/other/secret/dir
```

won't "work". In first case `ls` is not `/bin/ls`, in second case directories are different.